# Does soft deletes works on lumen framework? Limitations of Lumen?

Tags: laravel, api, lumen, soft-delete

I just wanted to know soft deletes on laravel is also works with lumen framework?

what are the limitations of lumen framework compared to laravel?

we are going to start a project with micro-services concept and considering about lumen framework.

Comment: yes soft deletes is working on Lumen. please visit https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SoftDeletes are supported in Lumen.

The limitations are:

- Configuration is different (not everything is out the box)
- The routing is very basic
- Missing useful artisan commands and helpers
- some additional Laravel packages won't work
- missing sub-domain routing, no optional parameters in routes

So basically you are using a stripped down version of Laravel and you are missing flexibility.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. and if we are working on micro service architecture what is the best option that we can choose? laravel or lumen?

Comment: Sorry, i was very busy and traveling : ) 

If your application is really tiny and you want performance = Lumen.

If your application needs to handle with languages, file storage, authentication, packages ... Go for Laravel.

Tip:
You can always edit the App/Http/Kernel.php and config/app.php and comment out providers, middleware or change settings to improve performance.

- if you are working with JWT, disable the middleware EncryptCookies, StartSession, ...